# Display 3 items by default in a multivalue field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a field collection which is a multivalue field with unlimited values.

when I opens the form, the field collection has a set of fields with "`add another item`" button. When I click the button, it adds one more set and so on.

Is it possible to have 3 sets by default and when the "`add another item`" button clicked, one more set is being added and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by jQuery, when page loads simulate the click event on the add more button using **onClick()**